# How to correctly write a transaction and bubble up the errors

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Ok because of the multiple levels of returns I am getting a little lost.

I am very new to ecto so here goes.

I'm trying to wrap my account creation in a transaction because it creates many child records etc.

So I have this so far:

```
def create_account(company_name, ...) do
  Repo.transaction(fn ->      
    case Account.create_account(%{
          # ... attributes here
        }) do
          ????
        end

        # insert other model records here using the same above case pattern matching

    account
  end) # transaction
end
```

The create_account on the ecto schema model looks like:

Account.ex

```
def create_account(attrs \\ %{}) do
  %Account{}
  |> Account.changeset(attrs)
  |> Repo.insert()
end
```

So now there are 3 levels of return values which I am not sure how to handle all together:

1. the happy path of a transaction seems to return:
   {:ok, model}
2. if the account.create_account insert fails, how to pass that errors down to the final return value so I can display that in the UI?
3. how to correctly rollback in any of the steps?

Comment: Also, check https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html#content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Repo.rollback](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:rollback/1) on failures. The docs say `The transaction will return the value given as {:error, value}`, so this can be done with pattern matching as you mention:

```
def create_account(company_name, ...) do
  Repo.transaction(fn ->
    account = case Account.create_account(%{ # ... attributes here }) do
      {:ok, account} -> account
      {:error, changeset} -> Repo.rollback(changeset)
    end

    # insert other model

    {:ok, account}
  end)
end
```

This way your function will return `{:ok, account}` on success, and `{:error, changeset}` on whatever failure it encounters. Because you're inserting multiple things you might want to differentiate them, maybe like so:

```
account = case Account.create_account(%{ # ... attributes here }) do
  {:ok, account} -> account
  {:error, changeset} -> Repo.rollback({:account, changeset})
end

case User.create_user(account, %{ # ... attributes here }) do
  {:ok, user} -> :ok
  {:error, changeset} -> Repo.rollback({:user, changeset})
end
```

In this case the function will return `{:ok, account}` if everything goes right, `{:error, {:account, account_changeset}}`, if account insertion fails, and `{:error, {:user, user_changeset}}` if user insertion fails.

Comment: this is great thanks, was really getting frustrated on how to handle this elegantly and handle all the cases correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The description of your intent sounds like a perfect use case for `Ecto.Multi`. It is a feature of Ecto that allows you to define complex data processing pipelines. There's a detailed explanation with more examples [here](https://curiosum.dev/blog/elixir-ecto-database-transactions?utm_medium=social&utm_source=stackoverflow), but overall the idea is simple and solid.

```
account = Account.changeset(%Account{}, params)
subscription = %Subscription{valid_until: ~D[2020-09-30]}

create_account =
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:insert_account, account)
  |> Ecto.Multi.run(:insert_subscription, fn repo, %{insert_account: account} ->
       subscription
       |> Map.put(:account_id, account.id)
       |> repo.insert()
     end)

Repo.transaction(create_account)
```

Feel free to refactor it to your liking; the basic idea is that each step is defined as a shorthand operation such as `insert` or as a function that returns `{:ok, record}` or `{:error, _}` - like in `Multi.run` because it needs to refer to previous step's artifact.

The pipeline is defined in the `create_account` variable, and then it only gets executed when `Repo.transaction(create_account)` is called. This way, all steps are run as a single transaction.

- If all steps succeed, `{:ok, %{insert_user: %User{...}, insert_subscription: %Subscription{...}}` is returned, and the transaction commits.
- If any step fails (for a step defined as a function, it means returning `{:error, _}`), an error tuple is returned, for instance `{:error, :insert_user, %Ecto.Changeset{}}` - and transaction is rolled back. In this case, the failure happened in the `insert_user` step.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#with/1) monad-like special form:

```
def create_account(company_name, ...) do
  Repo.transaction(fn ->      
    with {:ok, account} <- Account.create_account(...),
         {:ok, _} <- AnotherModel.create_record(...),
         ...
         {:ok, _} <- LastModel.create_record(...) do
      IO.puts("All fine")
      account
    else
      error ->
        IO.inspect(error, label: "Error happened") 
        Repo.rollback(:error_in_transaction)
    end
  end) # transaction
end
```

Comment: with makes things clean but maybe that is better for fetching and not for handling transactions for each one.

Comment: Why is that? `Kernel.SpecialForms.with/1` was explicitly designed to handle such cases. How would a gazillion of repetitions of `Repo.callback` be better?

Comment: oh I didn't realize this, let me research this thanks.